# UIStepper doesn't work in ios 4.1

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I have got UIStepper in the piece of code which is generated using the latest tools(5.1). Now I wish to make this app available for the 4.3 versions. When I specify the deployment target as 4.3 and run the app in the 4.3 simulator it crashes at the part of setting a value to the stepper.

step.value = [[array objectAtIndex:Indexpath.row] doubleValue];

This value is not getting set.

Comment: What exactly does not work?  With what part of functionality are you having problems?

Comment: As I'm using the stepper function, most of the methods aren't being functioned as expectd.

Comment: What do you mean by 'step button'?  Do you have example of code that you can provide?  What errors do you get... Be more specific....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using functionality that was not available in earlier versions of iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Quoting from docs:

> UIStepper Class Reference
>
> Inherits from 
>   UIControl : UIView : UIResponder : NSObject
>
> Conforms to
>   NSCoding (UIView)
>   UIAppearance (UIView)
>   UIAppearanceContainer (UIView)
>   NSObject (NSObject)
>
> Framework 
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework
>
> Availability
>   Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>   Declared in 
>   UIStepper.h